How to download a file from stream with Blazor SSR?
It's not clear to me how to download a file from a stream using Blazor SSR.
I read the documentation but it seems to consider only the WASM/Server cases, as it uses an @onclick event handler.
Is it necessary to use an API endpoint instead of the component approach?
